# Are there peer-reviewed papers studying the pros and cons of functional programming?

Tags: reference-request, programming-languages, lambda-calculus, functional-programming

Can somebody refer me to peer-reviewed papers studying the advantages or disadvantages of writing code in a functional style? Are there papers which discuss the applications of Lambda Calculus in fields such as Machine Learning, Language Design, etc.?

Comment: There are two separate questions here. I would make the second one about applications a new question.

Answer (score 7):

There is a famous paper "[Why Functional Programming Matters](http://www.cse.chalmers.se/~rjmh/Papers/whyfp.pdf)" by John Hughes. The main argument of this paper is the modularity of functional programs.

Also, the work by Chris Okasaki about functional data structures is very interesting. The article "Red-Black Trees in a Functional Setting" provides a very clear implementation of red-black trees using functional programming language, which is much simpler than their imperative implementation in the book "Introduction to Algorithms" by Tomas H. Cormen et al.

Comment: Link for the article [Red-Black Trees in a Functional Setting](http://www.cs.tufts.edu/~nr/cs257/archive/chris-okasaki/redblack99.ps‎) and [PhD thesis of Chris Okasaki about functional data structures](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~rwh/theses/okasaki.pdf‎).

Answer (score -1):

a semifamous high quality, free reference in this area is [Structure and intepretation of computer programs](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/) by Abelson and Sussman, MIT professors, some more info on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structure_and_Interpretation_of_Computer_Programs). they advocate functional programming as a way of understanding the theory and abstraction of programming such that understanding of functional programming will help one understand/apply the same principles in any language. they make some effort to discriminate it from/juxtapose it with what is called "imperative style" but without side-by-side comparisons.

Comment: When I read *studying the advantages or disadvantages of writing code in a functional style* I think of empirical studies observing the differences in practice. I don't think this book has results on that.